# Navigation bar not centered

Tags: html, css, center, navbar

I am currently coding a website for my design paper at uni. I am nearly done, but am having problems with the center alignment of the navigation bar.

It doesn't align to the center of the page like the text and image content does, it is slightly too far to the right. As shown below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMvxb.jpg]

Could anyone help me fix this problem?

EDIT: If anyone could also help me create the anchor for the icon part of the nav bar that would be awesome - I don't know what to use the `<a name=#home>` part on

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>S Gard</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet2.css" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico" />

    </head>
    <body style="position:absolute; height:100%;">
    <br />
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#about"><h2>ABOUT ME</h2></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#home"><img src="ICON.jpg" width="60%" height="60%"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#portfolio"><h2>PORTFOLIO</h2></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> <br />
        <div class="section1">
            <div class="center">
                <a name="#home"><img src="mainImage2.jpg" width="55%" height="55%" ></a>
                <br /><br />
                <div class="scroll">
                    <a href="#about"><img src="scrollArrow.png" width="5%" height="5%"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="about">
            <a name="about"><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></a>
            <h2>ABOUT ME</h2>
            <p class="para">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris et nibh vel erat efficitur egestas. Nullam ac urna id arcu posuere egestas. Praesent est magna, fringilla nec bibendum et, pellentesque eu mi. Nulla quis volutpat nisi, bibendum vulputate nisl. Donec porta odio eget velit dignissim vulputate. Nulla vitae sodales quam. Phasellus vulputate purus eu purus lobortis commodo.
Nulla pulvinar arcu a tempus maximus. Vestibulum eleifend, augue vel iaculis interdum, nisi ante lacinia tortor, ac porttitor nunc turpis eu ante. Aliquam et nisl et ex rhoncus vulputate sit amet eu dolor. Nunc risus elit, pulvinar nec sapien id, tincidunt dictum diam. Vestibulum gravida a metus non vehicula. Pellentesque in euismod dui, id consectetur nulla. Nunc libero ligula, pretium id orci et, pellentesque vestibulum dolor.
            </p>
            <div class="scroll">
                    <a href="#portfolio"><img src="scrollArrow.png" width="5%" height="5%"></a>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio">
            <a name="portfolio"><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></a>
            <h2>PORTFOLIO</h2>
            <p class="para">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris et nibh vel erat efficitur egestas. Nullam ac urna id arcu posuere egestas. Praesent est magna, fringilla nec bibendum et, pellentesque eu mi. Nulla quis volutpat nisi, bibendum vulputate nisl. Donec porta odio eget velit dignissim vulputate. Nulla vitae sodales quam. Phasellus vulputate purus eu purus lobortis commodo.
Nulla pulvinar arcu a tempus maximus. Vestibulum eleifend, augue vel iaculis interdum, nisi ante lacinia tortor, ac porttitor nunc turpis eu ante. Aliquam et nisl et ex rhoncus vulputate sit amet eu dolor. Nunc risus elit, pulvinar nec sapien id, tincidunt dictum diam. Vestibulum gravida a metus non vehicula. Pellentesque in euismod dui, id consectetur nulla. Nunc libero ligula, pretium id orci et, pellentesque vestibulum dolor.
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
html{
    background-color: white;
}

h1 {
    color: black;
    /*opacity: 0.7;*/
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

h2 {
    color: black;
    /*opacity: 0.7;*/
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

header{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    text-align: center;
}

header nav ul {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

header nav a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

header img{
    vertical-align: middle;
}

header nav a:hover, a:active {
    opacity: 0.4;
}

.section1{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}

.center{
    text-align: center;
}

.scroll a:hover, a:active {
    opacity: 0.4;
}

div.about{
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

p.para{

    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

div.portfolio{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: can you replicate your project in jsfiddle? easier for developers to solve your problem

Comment: sure thing, the images don't show up though https://jsfiddle.net/mnvs75ks/

Comment: what is it that is not being centered?

Comment: the image in the nav bar, you can see in the picture above on imgur that it is slightly aligned to the right compared to the scroll arrow

Answer (score 0):

Css:

```
<style>
    #nav{
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        border-width:1px 0;
        list-style:none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        text-align:center;
    }
    #nav li{
        display:inline;
    }
    #nav a{
         display:inline-block;
         padding:10px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: sorry where does this go? I have to have an external stylesheet as shown above, and not sure how/where this fits in with what I've got already.

Comment: @gardsama remove the style tags and add it to the end of your external stylesheet (recommended) or keep the style tags and put it after the html inside your html file (not recommended).

Comment: get code inside #nav{} and add it in your header nav{} #nav li do it the same as #nav{}

Comment: hey I did this but still get the same issue as shown in the picture above

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
html,body{

    margin:0;padding:0;
}
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/mnvs75ks/3/)